# Add user from Xamarin.Android app (Azure Active Directory)

Tags: azure, active-directory, xamarin.android

Hello i am trying to add a new user to an Active Directory app in Azure with GRAPH API but i do not know some URLs that i need in order to construct the client with C#, the only strings i am sure of is clientSecret.
Can anybody help?

```
 const string authString = "";
    const string clientID = "";
    const string clientSecret = "";
    const string resAzureGraphAPI = "";
    const string serviceRootURL = "";
    static Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(serviceRootURL);
   ActiveDirectoryClient adClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(
        serviceRoot,
        async () => await GetAppTokenAsync());
     private  void But_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a new user object.
        var newUser = new User()
        {
            // Required settings
            DisplayName = "Jay Hamlin",
            UserPrincipalName = "jayhamlin@cloudalloc.com",
            PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile()
            {
                Password = "H@ckMeNow!",
                ForceChangePasswordNextLogin = false
            },
            MailNickname = "JayHamlin",
            AccountEnabled = true,

            // Some (not all) optional settings
            GivenName = "Jay",
            Surname = "Hamlin",
            JobTitle = "Programmer",
            Department = "Development",
            City = "Dallas",
            State = "TX",
            Mobile = "214-123-1234",
        };

        // Add the user to the directory
        adClient.Users.AddUserAsync(newUser).Wait();
    }`
    private static async Task<string> GetAppTokenAsync()
    {
        // Instantiate an AuthenticationContext for my directory (see authString above).
        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authString, false);

        // Create a ClientCredential that will be used for authentication.
        // This is where the Client ID and Key/Secret from the Azure Management Portal is used.
        ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientID, clientSecret);

        // Acquire an access token from Azure AD to access the Azure AD Graph (the resource)
        // using the Client ID and Key/Secret as credentials.
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resAzureGraphAPI, clientCred);

        // Return the access token.
        return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
    }`
```

Comment: What is the issue you experience? Without knowing the extent of the problem, it is difficult to help you. Please do update your question.

Comment: const string authString = "";
    const string clientID = "";
    const string clientSecret = "";
    const string resAzureGraphAPI = "";
    const string serviceRootURL = "";
i dont know how to fill this strings

Answer (score 0):

In [this blog post](http://blog.jonathanhuss.com/getting-started-with-the-azure-active-directory-graph-client-library/) you can find a detailed walk through of the strings you are looking for:

1. `authString`

   - The `authority` which will return the `token`. This is normally a third-party endpoint whom will handle the `OAuth` authentication for you. An example is: `https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize`
2. `clientID`

   - This can be obtained from the Azure Applications portal
3. `resAzureGraphAPI`

   - The `Uri` to the Graph API. Most likely `https://graph.windows.net`.
4. `serviceRootURL`

   - The `Uri` to the domain of your Application. You should be able to find this under the Domains tab in Azure Active Directory

Additionally, you should avoid calling `.Wait();` on `AddUserAsync()` as it'll block execution. Instead, you should `await` the result.

Answer (score 0):

Please firstly read the [Azure Active Directory developer's guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-developers-guide) . In addition , when using :

```
  AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resAzureGraphAPI, clientCred);
```

means calling API using its app identity (instead of a user's identity) to get access tokens . You need to add application permissions in azure ad portal and grant permissions to users .Selecting an application permission will mean that your application can use the OAuth client credential flow to call the Graph API (without requiring a user). Please click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api) for more details.